mat-select crashing chrome 124 with STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW
Angular Material's Mat-select is crashing on Chrome 124
click on mat select crases chrome with error STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOWscreenshot
this is happening to material official website also
Go to below url and select basic select
https://v15.material.angular.io/components/select/overview

I have created a blog for temporary solution if anyone else is facing the same issue
https://medium.com/@sonugpc/mat-select-crashing-chrome-124-with-status-stack-overflow-b669cf0f1b5a

This is from the angular components GitHub: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28928

Solution provided by @SonuGupta not working for me. I am running on Angular 14

Chrome Fixed in latest Version. Please Update your browser
